# Heroku - 2 apps. How to connect Sinatra app with RoR app and use one database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, heroku, sinatra

I have on Heroku 2 apps - the first is in written in RoR and contains also the database. The second app is written in Sinatra framework and in this app I would need to work with data, which are saved in the database of the RoR app.

I've tried to look over some examples of how to load database data in Sinatra from the database of other app, but I wasn't very successful...

Could you give me please any advices, how to do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If all you want to do is share the database, you can do so by copying the DATABASE_URL config variable from one of the applications to the other.

You can get the value like this

```
heroku config --app <app_name_of_app1>
```

Once to have the value of `DATABASE_URL`, you can set it for the other app like this.

```
heroku config:add DATABASE_URL=<long_url_string_from_step_one> --app <app_name_of_app2>
```

Answer (score 0):

My best piece of advice would be to create an API on your rails app that your sinatra app consumes (you can use something like [fernet](https://github.com/hgmnz/fernet) for signed auth tokens).  Don't have more than one application connect to the same database.